# What is the maximum weight the Mark 6 Iron Man Suit can carry?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

I’m talking about it’s maximum weight lifted. The Mark VI was the version seen in *Iron Man 2*, *Avengers* and briefly in *Iron Man 3*

Comment: There's a difference between its maximum capacity and the maximum amount seen in the films

Comment: There is a [page](http://marveldirectory.com/miscellaneous/ironmanmarkvi.htm) that may give you the information you're looking for.

Comment: Movie version, comic version?

Comment: @Alith - The problem with that page is that large chunks of it appear to be fan-fiction, written by the site's owner. It looks kinda official (because of the big Marvel Banners at the top) but it really isn't.

Comment: Movie Version please.